# Not able to register/login facebook hidden service with Javascript enabled

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services

I'm trying to use facebook's hidden service to create an pseudonymous facebook account. For registering or logging in to facebook you have to enable javascript and I did that by clicking on the NoScript Button and selecting "Temporarily allow all this page". When I do that, the page starts to reload every few seconds, so it's impossible to enter my data. Therefore, I can neither register nor login.
I figure it has something to do with javascript or other scripts that I enable by whitelisting facebook's hidden service in NoScript. Is there another way to enable javascript or do I make another mistake?

Don't know whether this information is important, but my operation system is Ubuntu 16.04 and Tor browser bundle version is 6.0.4.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Use "Allow Scripts Globally", "Temporarily Allow All This Page" is often insufficient and the set of enables/disabled scripts is a fingerprint.

Comment: I remembered that even when I enable JavaScript on certain websites, some of it's functionalities still doesn't work. I remember sliding the security settings slider and it worked. Have you tried reducing the Security Level slider in Privacy and Security Settings? And clear your Noscript whitelist, as mentioned, it is a fingerprintable factor.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @canonizing I gave your suggestion a try, but unfortunately the page is still reloading every few seconds.

Comment: @m894v5n74v539nm8 the security settings are already set to 'low'. I even tried and enabled flash, cookies and all the other options in the privacy settings, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried their onion site?  https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebookcorewwwi.onion%2F&h=gAQHfvLlq&s=1

Comment: @m894v5n74v539nm8 Sorry if I used the wrong expression, that's what I'm actually trying to do. I thought that 'hidden service' referred to onion sites. With your link it's working though. Thanks!